# How to add a custom font in CSS?

Tags: css, webfonts

I was wondering if, anyone out there could help me figure out how to add a local font from my PC (WIN 10) to my local HTML website. Here is what i have tried so far.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: bubble;
    src: local(fonts/bubble.otf);
}
```

Here I want to take the font from my folder called "fonts" wich is located inside my website's folder and then choose bubble.otf, but it does not work

```
body {
    margin:0;
    font-family: bubble;
}
```

[image]

Comment: BTW, this code is inside the .css not in the .html!

Comment: You want to use `url` not `local`. The `local` value would never be a path, but the name of the font installed on the machine... like "Open Sans".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the font is in your websites folder, you should consider it to be not a local font. It's not a *locally installed* font but a part of your website, even though the website is on your computer.

So I think you misunderstood the meaning of `local`, and you should load the font as if it is a normal web font, using `url` instead of `local`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call your fonts from your local directory, you have to call it using the "url" instead of local as you used. Below is a workable example of what you want to achieve.

```
@font-face {
font-family: Segoel;
src: url('../font/segoel.eot'); /* IE9 Compatibility Modes */
src: url('../font/segoel.eot?') format('eot'),  /* IE6-IE8 */
url('../font/segoel.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
url('../font/segoel.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
url('../font/segoel.svg#svgsegoel') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */  }
```

However, linking to online font repositories such as [Google font](https://fonts.google.com/), [fontsquirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator) directly are most effective ways especially when you want to use variety of fonts.